# fulltext - how to select number of results faster?

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

I'm working on a job search engine. Using fulltext on 4 fields on a 1.5M rows myisam table.

I use following type of SQL in order to display number of results.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM jobs WHERE MATCH (title, company, state, city) AGAINST ('Senior Environmental Engineer +"San Francisco"')
```

My problem is that it is too slow (up to 5 seconds). I did a research and tried alternative SQLs but there is no real improvement. How can I make it faster?

EDIT: Except getting number of result count everything works great currently. So I just need a way to get number of results faster. If it is possible to get a rough number of results, that would be great as well.

Comment: If you're implementing full-text searches, SQL is definitely *not* what I'd suggest you use. Try looking into other database alternatives.

Comment: try splitting each one apart... i.e. ... `WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST ('Senior Environmental Engineer +"San Francisco"') AND MATCH(company) AGAINST ('Senior Environmental Engineer +"San Francisco"')`

Comment: So it is not possible to get # of results faster?

Comment: @John , thats not possible because there is 1 fulltext index for 4 fields.

Comment: I've seen it done before. and its supposed to go a lot faster

Comment: @JohnRuddell /* SQL Error (1191): Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list */

Comment: @JohnRuddell I changed the indexes and tried it. It is plain BS what you are saying. Thank you.

Comment: @user3841653 of course you need to change the indexes... i didn't clarify that in what I said... but if you index each one separately then run it like that it goes a lot faster